# EntLib returning spaces from blank db field

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-library, business-objects

I have a column in SQL Server which is blank (empty string). After calling my sproc via EntLib 5.0, however, the property in my business object has spaces in it--the same number as the width of the database column.

Why is EntLib populating my property with spaces?

Comment: How is the column defined in your db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is probably defined as char(x) where x is the number of spaces that are being returned.

If you want blank to be an empty string change your column definition to varchar.